# Can't apply absolute css positioning to my own composite button

Tags: css, gwt

Here is a strange problem I am having,  althougt I have a work around I would still like to understand why it is happening.

Here is my Composite class

```
    import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
    import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
    import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.HasClickHandlers;
    import com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerRegistration;
    import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.*;

    public class ExpandingOvalButton extends Composite implements HasClickHandlers
    {   
        private PushButton button;
        private Label label = new Label();
        private AbsolutePanel panel = new AbsolutePanel();

        public ExpandingOvalButton(String text)
        {       
            int width = 40;
            initWidget( panel );
            Image image = new Image( "icons/ovalBlueButton.png");
            label.setText(text);
            width = width + (text.length() * 8);
            String widthStr = width + "px";
            image.setWidth(widthStr);
            image.setHeight("50px");
            button = new PushButton( image );
            button.setWidth(widthStr);
            button.setHeight("50px");
            panel.setSize(widthStr, "50px");                
            panel.add(button, 0, 0);
            panel.add(label, 18, 14);
        }

        ...
```

It works perfectly for me when I add it to a flex table along with other widget and then I can apply css styles to the flextable and position it fine.  Problem is if I want to apply css positioning to a ExpandingOvalButton instance which does not sit inside of an other panel it does not work properly.

```
private ExpandingOvalButton startBtn = new ExpandingOvalButton("Start");
startBtn .getElement().setId("myId");


#myId
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 120px;
}
```

This will NOT position itself 30% from the left side.
However if I add startBtn  to a Panel and then apply the same CSS style to the Panel it WILL position itself 30% from the left.

```
panel.add(startBtn);
panel.getElement().setId("myId");
```

Anyone come across this before or know what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code for AbsolutePanel, you will find this in the constructor:

```
DOM.setStyleAttribute(getElement(), "position", "relative");
```

This has priority over the styles declared in your css. You can force it to use absolute positioning by doing something similar:

```
DOM.setStyleAttribute(startBtn.getElement(), "position", "absolute");
```

Comment: Cheers,  it works now.  What I don't understand is why when I declare "position:  absolute" in my CSS for the startBtn element that this makes no difference.  See   contentTable.add( startBtn );
 
  startBtn.getElement().setId("myId");  and my css class = 
#myId {
 position: absolute;
 left: 10%;
 top: 130px;
}    it only works if I use your line  DOM.setStyleAttribute(startBtn.getElement(), "position", "absolute");

Comment: Don't know if this is the same as your setup, but for our GWT styles, we often have to append the !important tag to the css property, and then it will override what GWT sets (usually).